# Spring @Scheduled execute method executes thrice in VPS

Tags: spring, tomcat, vps

I am using Spring 3.0.6.RELEASE. I have two schedulers using @Scheduled annotation configured in my application with cron attribute

```
@Scheduled(cron ="0 00 23 * * SUN-SAT")
public void execute(){
          logger.debug("Scheduler-1 executing...");
           }

@Scheduled(cron="0 00 22 * * WED")  
public void execute(){
    logger.debug("Scheduler-2 executing...");
           }
```

Both the schedulers are registered as beans in spring-servlet config file and i have not used @Configurable annotation. i have also ensured that the beans are registered only once. it runs only once in my development machine perfectly. but, it executes thrice in my production vps. Based on the logs it executes thrice like shown below

```
03:00:11,409 DEBUG PeriodicUnPaymentCheckScheduler:60 - Scheduler-1 executing...
03:00:11,411 DEBUG PeriodicUnPaymentCheckScheduler:60 - Scheduler-1 executing...
03:00:11,412 DEBUG PeriodicUnPaymentCheckScheduler:60 - Scheduler-1 executing...
```

Please let me know your views why it is executing thrice.Thanks all for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just upgraded the spring version to 3.2.0.Release. this problem was resolved!